# $f$ is holomorphic and $|f'(z)|<1$ in a convex domain $D$ then $\frac{f(z_2)-f(z_1)}{z_2-z_1}\in Conv\{f'(z):z\in D\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is holomorphic and $|f'(z)|<1$ in a convex domain $D$. I wish to show that for all $z_1,z_2\in D$ , $\frac{f(z_2)-f(z_1) }{z_2-z_1}\in Conv\{f'(z) , z\in D\}$.

Using the line integral and the fact that $D$ is convex, one can show that $|f(z_2)-f(z_1)|=|\int_{[z_1,z_2]}f'(z)dz|\le \int_{[z_1,z_2]}|f'(z)|dz \le \int_{[z_1,z_2]}1= |z_2-z_1|$. So we get that $|f(z_2)-f(z_1)|\le |z_2-z_1|$. Thus $|\frac{f(z_2)-f(z_1)}{z_2-z_1}|\le 1$ so $\frac{f(z_2)-f(z_1)}{z_2-z_1} \in B(0,1)$ for all $z_1 ,z_2\in D$ . The fact that $|f'(z)|<1$ the $Conv\{f'(z) : z\in D\}$ is also a subset of $B(0,1)$. However I don't succeed to proceed from this point.

Comment: Do you mean “convex domain”?

Comment: @MartinR yes indeed, edited. Thanks for correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer assuming that $Conv(A)$ stands for the closed convex hull of $A$:

$\frac {f(z_2)-f(z_1)} {z_2-z_1} =\int _0^{1} f'(tz_2+(1-t)z_1)\, dt$. If you just write down a typical Riemann sum for this integral you will see that each Riemann sum is  a convex combination of a finite number of values of $f'(z)$ with $z \in D$. Hence $\frac {f(z_2)-f(z_1)} {z_2-z_1}$ belongs to the closed convex hull of $\{f'(z): z \in D\}$.